# xcode error: "Use of unresolved identifier: GGLContext" (without CocoaPods)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, google-signin

I have done web development for a couple years and this is my first project with an iOS application. I have followed all of the instructions from Google's [Get the Google Sign-in SDK for iOS](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sdk/#old_versions) (without CocoaPods), and I tried simulating the application and I'm getting this error: `Use of unresolved identifier 'GGLContext'`

This is the code that is copied from Google's page and put into AppDelegate.swift :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  // Initialize Google sign-in
  var configureError: NSError?
  GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&configureError)  // THIS LINE HAS THE ERROR
  assert(configureError == nil, "Error configuring Google services: \(configureError)")

  //GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().delegate = self
  GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = MY_CLIENT_ID

        return true
    }
```

Any help?

Comment: Have you added `#import <GoogleSignIn/GoogleSignIn.h>` in your project's bridging header, as it says to do here? https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in#enable_sign-in

Comment: That wasn't working for some reason so I did `#import "exact\location\of\GoogleSignIn.h"`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I faced the same problem as you then I decided to read the [Google's Tutorial](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/sign-in?ver=swift) again, looking for the word "manually", and here's what they say:

> ***Note***: If you manually installed the SDK, you should instead configure the **GIDSignIn** object **directly**, using the **client ID** found in the **GoogleService-Info.plist** file:
>
> > *GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().clientID = kClientID*

So just comment the lines related to **GGLContext** and I think that should work for this problem.

Comment: You are the life saver

Comment: @NaveedAhmad lol Thanks man! I'm just trying to contribute a little with this community that helps me so much!